# How to upload a video using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

Scenario - I want to test the performance of uploading feature of the application, In my case with the recording, I am not able to upload a video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to record upload request you need to put the file(s) you will be uploading into "bin" folder of your JMeter installation, this way JMeter's proxy will be able to locate the file and properly intercept the request. It is applicable to any file types.

References:

- [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
- [Apache JMeter proxy Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
- [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter)